Why Mesh Keeps Deforming with Bones that do not Deform?
I Parented the mesh to the rig and remove weight paint from the parts I don't want to be affect by the bones, but still something is still deforming the mesh.
This guy's butt cheeks are supposed to be smooth.



hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Hover the mis-deformed area, and type ⎈ Ctrl⇧ ShiftX to sample the groups affecting this area. From there, you can select the groups that you don't want to affect that area, and paint them to zero.
